# what(): Unexpected error from cudaGetDeviceCount(). Did you run some cuda functions before calling NumCudaDevices()

Tags: python, linux, pytorch, gpu

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04.

I am trying to test a Neural Network and I have some scripts which are written in python that try to use the GPU. My scripts work fine and I can train and test the model I am trying to build.

However, I noticed that if for some reason my script does not arrive at its end (e.g., I have an error at the end of the `main` function) I cannot start again another script to try again to test the model.

What I get is the following error:

```
(software1) myusername@mylaptopname:~/folder1$ bash experiments/test.sh 
Using tensorboardX
[log - coco.py] in class COCO
[log - coco.py] in class COCO1
importing1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'c10::Error'
  what():  Unexpected error from cudaGetDeviceCount(). Did you run some cuda functions before calling NumCudaDevices() that might have already set an error? Error 804: forward compatibility was attempted on non supported HW
Exception raised from device_count_impl at ../c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:97 (most recent call first):
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string) + 0x42 (0x7febf4b41a22 in /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/software1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: c10::detail::torchCheckFail(char const*, char const*, unsigned int, std::string const&) + 0x5b (0x7febf4b3e3db in /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/software1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #2: <unknown function> + 0xd513 (0x7febf4d9f513 in /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/software1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10_cuda.so)
frame #3: c10::cuda::device_count_ensure_non_zero() + 0xe (0x7febf4d9f54e in /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/software1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10_cuda.so)
frame #4: THCudaInit(THCState*) + 0x21 (0x7feb7984a541 in /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/software1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so)
frame #5: <unknown function> + 0x2b05964 (0x7feb796ca964 in /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/software1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so)
frame #6: at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const + 0x3a (0x7feb427dc592 in /home/myusername/folder1/src/lib/model/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #7: void std::__invoke_impl<void, at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}>(std::__invoke_other, at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}&&) + 0x24 (0x7feb427dd179 in /home/myusername/folder1/src/lib/model/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #8: std::__invoke_result<at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}>::type std::__invoke<at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}>(std::__invoke_result&&, (at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}&&)...) + 0x33 (0x7feb427dce70 in /home/myusername/folder1/src/lib/model/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #9: std::call_once<at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}>(std::once_flag&, at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}&&)::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const + 0x27 (0x7feb427dc893 in /home/myusername/folder1/src/lib/model/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #10: std::call_once<at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}>(std::once_flag&, at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}&&)::{lambda()#2}::operator()() const + 0x2b (0x7feb427dc8c1 in /home/myusername/folder1/src/lib/model/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #11: std::call_once<at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}>(std::once_flag&, at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}&&)::{lambda()#2}::_FUN() + 0x12 (0x7feb427dc8d6 in /home/myusername/folder1/src/lib/model/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #12: <unknown function> + 0x1247f (0x7fec01f6347f in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0)
frame #13: <unknown function> + 0x444c8 (0x7feb427dc4c8 in /home/myusername/folder1/src/lib/model/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #14: void std::call_once<at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}>(std::once_flag&, at::Context::lazyInitCUDA()::{lambda()#1}&&) + 0x86 (0x7feb427dc973 in /home/myusername/folder1/src/lib/model/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #15: at::Context::lazyInitCUDA() + 0x3a (0x7feb427dc60a in /home/myusername/folder1/src/lib/model/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #16: <unknown function> + 0x44458 (0x7feb427dc458 in /home/myusername/folder1/src/lib/model/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #17: <unknown function> + 0x4447f (0x7feb427dc47f in /home/myusername/folder1/src/lib/model/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #18: <unknown function> + 0x11b8a (0x7fec021c0b8a in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
frame #19: <unknown function> + 0x11c91 (0x7fec021c0c91 in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
frame #20: _dl_catch_exception + 0xe5 (0x7fec020d7915 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
frame #21: <unknown function> + 0x160bf (0x7fec021c50bf in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
frame #22: _dl_catch_exception + 0x88 (0x7fec020d78b8 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
frame #23: <unknown function> + 0x155fa (0x7fec021c45fa in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
frame #24: <unknown function> + 0x134c (0x7fec01f4c34c in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2)
frame #25: _dl_catch_exception + 0x88 (0x7fec020d78b8 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
frame #26: _dl_catch_error + 0x33 (0x7fec020d7983 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
frame #27: <unknown function> + 0x1b59 (0x7fec01f4cb59 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2)
frame #28: dlopen + 0x4a (0x7fec01f4c3da in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2)
<omitting python frames>
frame #31: python() [0x685611]
frame #32: python() [0x5c5530]
frame #47: python() [0x5f38f1]
frame #53: python() [0x600f54]
frame #54: python() [0x5c5530]

experiments/test.sh: line 20: 33055 Aborted                 (core dumped) python test.py ddd --exp_id software1 --dataset nuscenes --val_split mini_val --run_dataset_eval --num_workers 8 --nuscenes_att --velocity --gpus 0 --pointcloud --radar_sweeps 6 --max_pc_dist 60.0 --pc_z_offset -0.0 --load_model ../exp/ddd/software1/model_last.pth --flip_test
```

The only way I have to solve this problem is to reboot my laptop and this is annoying of course.

I know that it is quite generic what I am asking but I was wondering if there is a way to *reset* the use of the GPU since to me this looks like a problem in which the allocation of GPU has not been "closed" correctly. Indeed, every time I reboot the problem disappears.

Could you help me solve this problem?